# Adding a new user on Ubuntu server

Tags: server, adduser

I have been trying to add a new user. I typed in `adduser` then username and also tried `useradd` then username. It does seem to add a user, but when I login I only get a dollar sign instead of `user@servername`. I have tried adding rules to allow me into the sudo for that username, but why do I only get the dollar sign?

Comment: The `$` indicates the plain old shell.  Do `sudo usermod --shell /usr/bin USERNAME` and replace "USERNAME" with the name of the user.

Comment: Or create user "testuser" with **sudo** privileges one-liner: useradd testuser -G sudo -d /home/testuser -s /bin/bash -m -c "Test User" && echo testuser:P4s5W0rD | chpasswd && sed -ri 's/^# (%sudo.+ALL=\(ALL\).+NOPASSWD: ALL)/\1/' /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 15):

You might have either accidentally used "useradd" instead of "adduser" - which adds the user, but does not set up a profile for him/her - or you might be missing the "skeleton" files in /etc/skel which normally set up a default user account.

Please do `sudo userdel username` (where `username` is the name of the account you're creating), then `sudo adduser username` and post the output here.  You SHOULD get something like the following:

```
me@banshee:~$ sudo adduser noob
Adding user `noob' ...
Adding new group `noob' (1005) ...
Adding new user `noob' (1005) with group `noob' ...
Creating home directory `/home/noob' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
Changing the user information for noob
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: 
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n]
```

If you do all that and the user still does not get a full prompt, then you're missing some files from /etc/skel - please post back, and we can help further.  I think you just accidentally used `useradd` instead of `adduser`, though, which does not do ANY of the above stuff - it just creates a system account and that's it, no homedir, no nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I don't know what's the default behaviour for adduser but I think you should specify the options explicity. Like:

```
sudo useradd -d /home/testuser -m testuser
```

the command above set the home directory for the new user and create it (`-m`) if necessary. Then you need to set the password for the new user:

```
sudo passwd testuser
```

There are also several other options, check the man page to see them:

```
man adduser
```