# Full Ubuntu Desktop via VNC client

Tags: vnc

I'm new to Linux and I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Server).

My challenge is that I am trying to create a VNC desktop that will show the full ubuntu desktop but for some or other reason when I connect via the VNC client I'm confronted with the root's X desktop.

Answer (score 0):

For serving VNC off of a headless server, you'd best go with [tightvncserver](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tightvncserver); so install that.
Also, make sure that you have a [desktop installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/53577/126726) already.

Then, switch to the user account you want to start a server for:

```
root@box $ su some_user
Password:
```

(If you need to create a new user first, see [Adding a new user on Ubuntu server](https://askubuntu.com/q/221009/126726).)

As the user, create a VNC server instance:

```
some_user@box $ vncserver -geometry 800x600 :5
```

Then finally, as the client point your VNC client to `box:5`.

Answer (score 0):

Kill your running VNC with the command below,

vncserver -kill :1,

Open the  below file in a text editor,

```
~/.vnc/xstartup
```

Search for this line -

```
x-window-manager &
```

and replace it with

```
gnome-session &
```

Now save and exit this file, then launch your VNC and check.